# Question made from Sir Tim Berners-Lee in TeX.SE?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Seems to me that some months ago I saw a question made **from** Sir Tim Berners-Lee, and seems to me in this TeX/LaTeX room (but maybe I'm wrong about TeX).

I cannot re-found, do you want help me?

Sorry for the post being off-topic, if you know a better place to make this question... let me know!

Comment: Hi! This should go to the meta site. However, there is no user with "berners" in their nickname...

Comment: see also: https://www.google.de/search?q=berners-lee+site:tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm not exactly sure in TEX, I remember so, but I can wrong. I'm sure in Stackoverflow. Another user answered to first answer sayng.... "Do you seen who is the OP :D"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sir Timothy John "Tim" Berners-Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Berners-Lee) is also known as **TimBL**. The only [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1162584/timbl) having that name is on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com):

[image]

He has asked only [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31345230/914686) to date (Jul 10 at 15:56). Moreover, he is involved only with StackOverflow.

No other similar users exist on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com).